# Custom Permission Check in LWC always returning undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-permission

I am trying to disable a button on an LWC based on a custom permission, but I cannot seem to make it work. Here is the code involved:

js controller (let's call it actions):

```
import hasResetSecQuestionsPermission from '@salesforce/userPermission/Reset_Security_Questions';

export default class actions extends LightningElement { 
  get disableResetSecQuestionsButton() {
    return !hasResetSecQuestionsPermission;
  }
}
```

Html lightning button:

```
<lightning-button
  variant="neutral"
  name="resetSecurityQuestionsButton"
  data-id="ResetSecurityQuestions"
  label="Reset Security Questions"
  title="Reset Security Questions"
  onclick={handleClick}
  disabled={disableResetSecQuestionsButton}
  class="slds-align_absolute-center"
></lightning-button>
```

I am aware that in this case `hasResetSecQuestionsPermission` should return `undefined` if the running user has not been assigned the permission, and `true` if they have. But it seems to return `undefined` for me even if I have the permission. I have checked I have it for sure by running

```
System.debug(FeatureManagement.checkPermission('Reset_Security_Questions'));
```

anonymously and it returns true.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like error in the import statement, it should be
@salesforce/customPermission

Comment: yes - yes it was. Thank you! What a thing to get stuck on

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who faced the same issue but is actually using the correct import statement:

- try to open the same component in incognito browser mode
- or enable `Debug Mode` for your user

In my case, that was a Salesforce caching issue.